# List of tags not available ColdFusion 9 script syntax?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm looking for a complete list of tags that are not available in ColdFusion 9 script syntax.

Example:

- CFSetting: is one example that is available in [Railo](http://wiki.getrailo.org/wiki/TAG:CFSETTING) but not in CF9 for use in cfscript
- CFDocument: I can't find this one so far.

Comment: Not an official list, but the closest I have found is: https://github.com/CFCommunity/CFScript-Community-Components/blob/master/readme.md

Comment: Oh! I just noticed that github thing is a replication of what I said below.  I didn't mean to repeat what you suggested, Leigh; but I assure you that is my own work, and its plagiarism on github was unbeknownst to me.  Not that I mind, but I will give my namesake Tuttle a bit of a nudge for that one. ;-)

Comment: No worries. I did not post it as answer because I thought there might be an official list I had overlooked. But yours seems to be as close as it gets. If imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, you should be feeling duly flattered ;-)

Comment: Just a note on my comment above, I have spoken to Adam Tuttle regarding the usage of my work on that project, and it's all fine as far as I'm concerned.  It just raised a slight flag for me to see something I had written being used in a context I didn't know about, even if its usage in that context is A-OK with me.  I'd like to remove the "plagiarism" reference above, but I cannot edit a comment, so hopefully this follow-up will explain that it's not a problem, and using the "P word" was a bit strong on my part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not an official list by any measure, but this is a list I presented to a private forum a while back, and it didn't receive too much correction (and those corrections have been integrated).  It was in the context of what CF does and doesn't need to be implemented, to claim 100% coverage in CFScript.

Summary of omissions:

These ones are significant omissions:

```
<cfcollection>
<cfexchangecalendar>   
<cfexchangeconnection> 
<cfexchangecontact>     
<cfexchangefilter>     
<cfexchangemail>
<cfexchangetask>
<cfexecute>
<cfindex>
<cfinvoke> (support for dynamic method names)
<cflogin>
<cfloginuser>
<cflogout>
<cfmodule>
<cfoutput> (implementation of query looping with grouping)
<cfparam> (fix the bug in that enforced requiredness doesn’t work (ie: param name="foo";))
<cfsearch>
<cfsetting>
<cfwddx>
<cfzip>
<cfzipparam>
```

There’s a reasonable case for these ones to be implemented:

```
<cfassociate>   
<cfcache>       
<cfcontent>     
<cfflush>       
<cfhtmlhead>   
<cfheader>     
<cfntauthenticate>     
<cfprint>     
<cfschedule>   
<cfsharepoint>
```

These ones... I’m ambivalent:

```
<cfgridupdate>
<cfinsert>
<cfobjectcache>
<cfregistry>
<cfreport>
<cfreportparam>
<cftimer>
<cfupdate>
```

We don’t need these ones at all, I think:

```
<cfajaximport>
<cfajaxproxy>
<cfapplet>
<cfcalendar>
<cfchart>
<cfchartdata>
<cfchartseries>
<cfcol>
<cfdiv>
<cfdocument>
<cfdocumentitem>
<cfdocumentsection>
<cffileupload>
<cfform>
<cfformgroup>
<cfformitem>
<cfgraph>
<cfgraphdata>
<cfgrid>
<cfgridcolumn>
<cfgridrow>
<cfinput>
<cflayout>
<cflayoutarea>
<cfmap>
<cfmapitem>
<cfmediaplayer>
<cfmenu>
<cfmenuitem>
<cfpod>
<cfpresentation>
<cfpresentationslide>
<cfpresenter>
<cfselect>
<cfsilent>
<cfslider>
<cfsprydataset>
<cftable>
<cftextarea>
<cftextinput>
<cftooltip>
<cftree>
<cftreeitem>
<cfwindow>
```

If there's anything here that you think ought to be included in CFScript, please raise an issue here - http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html - and cross reference the issue number here.

HTH.

Comment: Good list. I believe `cfimap` support was added in CF9 Update 1.

Comment: Oops, yeah sorry.  That was one of the things I got pulled-up on.  Forgot to integrate it / remove it from the list.  I'll update my original list.

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that there are no commands that are not available as script as you can extend and write the missing bits using cfc's.

Thus wrap your favourite missing <cftag in a cfc and call it using new

However, here is a list of what is supported
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html

Comment: I think this is a pretty limp response, Dale: Obviously we can roll our own, but that's not the question here.  It's this sort of response / mind process than landed us with CF9 implementing CFScript omissions with CFCs in /adobe/com/, which means the language starts to completely depart of the precedent set with all the rest of the language to date.

It's a poor solution to a very real requirement.